# write to file becomes erasing all data

Tags: java

i am trying to write to file but it only saves the new line, I want to move the other lines as well to the new file.
i did not use flush because i read that close(); automatically flushes.

e.g old data

```
ken|Password|500
test|Password|200
kenny|Password|100
testing|Password|300
```

new data

```
ken|Password|1000
```

expected data

```
ken|Password|1000
test|Password|200
kenny|Password|100
testing|Password|300




 public static void replace()throws IOException{

    try {

        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Username: ");
        String Username = read.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Chips to Add: ");
        String addChips = read.nextLine();

        read = new Scanner(new File("players.dat"));
        String line;
        String[] details;
        String input = "";

        File fout = new File("newplayers.dat");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

        while (read.hasNextLine()){
            line = read.nextLine();
            details = line.split("\\|");

            if(details[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Username)){
                int newChips = Integer.parseInt(addChips) + Integer.parseInt(details[2]);
                String totalChips = Integer.toString(newChips);
                input = details[0] + "|" + details[1] + "|" + totalChips +"\n";
                bw.write(input);
                System.out.println("Chips Added.");
            }


        }
        read.close();
        bw.close();

    }catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println("file not found");
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't read and write to the same file at the same time. Either you read the whole file to memory, and then close it and open it for writing and write everything, or you write to a different file, and then replace the old file with the new file.

Comment: Sure you can.  Just not the way posted.  A RandomAccessFile, for example.

Comment: hmm I see I guess i'll do the write to new file and replace but in the event that my new file is blank what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to read and buffer the input before creating the writer. There are many ways to do this, e.g.:

```
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("players.dat"));
read = new Scanner(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what you need to do :

- Read the entire file.
- Re-write the file, but when the line's name is the same as the one of the new data line (ken in that case) you simply write this line instead of the original one and skip to next line.
- Note that you can't read and write from the same file at same time so you will have to write in a new file, then delete the old one and rename the new one (as I explained you how to do on your other question).

It seems to me that you already know how to parse data from files so I think you should be able to close this issue with these steps.